# 2-of-3 multisignature account with limitations on withdrawal

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature, regtest

I want to create a 2 of 3 multi-signature account from where one can withdraw money only after a certain period of time. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to add an `OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY` guard before the `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` statement in your output script.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0112.mediawiki